# dropdown get option value using option text using contains method jquery returns wrong value

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select

I have a dropdown as follows:

```
<select id="lang" >
       <option value="1">php</option>
       <option value="2">java j2ee</option>
        <option value="3">asp</option>
       <option value="4">java</option>
  </select>
```

What I am doing is trying get the option value using option text as follows;

Suppose java is option text so what I tried is as follows:

```
var a = $('#lang option:contains("java")').val();
```

**But I am getting option value as 2 instead of 4 (which is correct and expected)**

I am getting wrong because I am trying method `contains`. Please guide me how can I get exact value?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uxjjtq/268/)

Comment: JQuery `:contains()` the same as `.indexOf()` do so you will get 2,4 if you use `.each()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using `.filter()`.

```js
alert($('#lang option').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == 'java' }).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang">
  <option value="1">php</option>
  <option value="2">java j2ee</option>
  <option value="3">asp</option>
  <option value="4">java</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.html()` to check content:

```js
$('#lang option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == 'java') {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang">
  <option value="1">php</option>
  <option value="2">java j2ee</option>
  <option value="3">asp</option>
  <option value="4">java</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or you can use `text()` to check.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the element with exact text use Regex

```
var regex = new RegExp("^java$");
var a = $('#lang option').filter(function () {
    return regex.test($(this).text()); 
}).val();
alert(a);
```